# Clean /boot on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

When I boot my Ubuntu server, I have this warning message:

```
 => /boot is using 100.0% of 235MB
```

And when I look into /boot, I have a lot of files which are dependent of the version of the kernel.

```
ls -al /boot/
abi-3.13.0-*-generic
config-3.13.0-*-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-*-generic
System.map-3.13.0-*-generic
vmlinuz-3.13.0-*-generic
```

Where the * correspond to 24,35,36,37,39,40,41,43,44

How can I clean this securely ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the old kernel versions that you're not using any more.  I normally keep the last two or three versions installed, and remove the older ones.  So for example you can run

```
apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-{24,35,36,37,39,40}-generic
```

When you do that, the old files that you listed above will be removed from /boot.

Answer (score 1):

I use this write-only bit of scripting to do the job. I think I found this in a previous answer to a similar question on StackExchange, but I cannot find it just now. Anyway - this script keeps the running version of the kernel and related files but deletes all other versions:

`dpkg -l 'linux-' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/(.)-([^0-9]+)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* ([^ ])./\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge`

I have spent quite some time looking at it and I have managed to explain to myself how it works at some point...

Comment: Thanks for your response but I can't run this command on my production server lol. Nobody do that lol.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a tool that automates this chore, in case it helps anyone else: https://github.com/erichs/bootnukem.

Comment: Please add some more details